# Hidden file on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I have a super old program on a Windows 10 computer with which I saved a .PIC file that I want to transfer to a Mac to view the image. The file seems to save ok because when I try saving it again, I'm told that the file already exists. Unfortunately, I can't view it in the directory. When I selected the "Show hidden files, folders, and drives" option under File Explorer, nothing changes. How do I find and transfer this file?

Comment: I already did that, as mentioned in my query.

Answer (score 1):

You can open a cmd prompt at the directory where you think it is saved by holding down shift button and rightclicking, and select open shell here.
When you have a shell open, you could verify if the file is really there, by typing `dir`.
If you see your file listed, you can just rename it with `rename .PIC whatever`, and hopefully it will show up in your file explorer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that doesn't work either (I don't see the file). Again, when I go to "Save As" I see the previously saved file, but I can't transfer it.

Comment: Try `dir /adh` instead.